# Why doesn't EditText lose focus after soft keyboard is hidden?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, lost-focus

How does `EditText` still have focus after the soft keyboard is hidden (user presses *Done/Enter/Search* button)?

Could you please provide me some explanation about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app and *Android* soft keyboard ([stock one](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/jb-dev/java/src/com/android/inputmethod/latin)) are different app processes. And while *Android* takes care of "notifying" the soft keyboard app on your app's `EditText` **focus requests**, neither *Android* nor the soft keyboard app should be responsible for your app's `EditText` **focus changes**. Your app has enough callbacks from the soft keyboard at its disposal to clear focus.

Answer (score 1):

That's the default Android behaviour. You can call view.clearFocus() on Enter key press to override this.

Answer (score -1):

**- Add Following Line of Code in your Specific Activity.**

```
EditText edt_user = findViewById(R.id.edt_user);      
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(edt_user,0);

    edt_user.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

                edt_user.clearFocus();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```